# How do I turn off all flake8 stylistic errors and leave programmatic errors?

Tags: python, flake8

I'm using flake8 with Atom to do Python linting. I would prefer not to see stylistic errors, just programmatic ones. I.e. I don't care if I didn't put the proper number of spaces around an operator, but I still want to know if a variable is used before initialization.

I am aware that I can put specific error numbers in the "ignore" section of the flake8ini.rc, but is there a way to turn off all stylistic errors in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you really just want to run `pyflakes` and not `pycodestyle`. You should be able to disable `pycodestyle` by ignoring all `E` and `F` violations:

```
[flake8]
ignore = E,F
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer before I tried that. It's still giving me E and F errors. I restarted Atom to be sure. Is this the right syntax?

Comment: Never mind, it's working. I had put flake8ini.rc in the wrong directory.

Comment: Shouldn't it be all E and W violations:

https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes